# How to enforce the cron job to run on PST time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq-cron

I want to schedule a cron Job to run on 5 AM PST to 8 PM PST? I just want to know how to enforce my job to be run on PST?. I am new to this cron Job.

// code

```
cron: "0 5-20 * * *"
```

Comment: is it sidekiq cron?

Comment: Yes, it's a sidekiq cron only

Comment: Not sure it will work or not, but can you please try this one `'0 5-20 * * * America/California'`

Comment: Let me know whether its working or not

Comment: ok, I will check and update

Comment: l Where do you get this time zone kind of information ? I want to know how do I define a timezone for different timings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199054/discussion-between-selvi-and-vishal).

Comment: did it work for you ?

Comment: Yes this code works fine cron: "*/5 11-20 * * * Asia/Kolkata". when I give cron: "0 5-20 * * * America/California" and it doesn't work at all. I want to know whether the America/California is correct time zone?Where your are picked the time zone?

Comment: Give me 5 mins, i will get back to you

Comment: your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, This itself worked cron: "0 5-20 * * *". Thanks Vishal

Comment: Glad to hear that. should I post it as an answer? will you accept and upvote it?

Comment: yes ok You can..

Comment: I added an answer. please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give timezone to cron by below way.

```
"0 5-20 * * * America/Los_Angeles"
```

If you are not sure which timezone will it come just fetch records of timezones of rails with this command `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all` and select `TZInfo::DataTimezone`.